# C# AddMemoryPressure performance

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Does C# AddMemoryPressure call add a connection to the specific object it's being invoked for? I've seen it show up a lot in our performance traces, and I want to batch together calls every 10MB or so, but if it inspects the stack to attach the pressure information to a specific object it thinks is being allocated then that won't work

Comment: What object are you talking about? AddMemoryPressure is a static method that takes a `long` parameter. It is not associated with any object except in your head, huh, program.

Comment: AMP is a lot like violence.  If it gets you into trouble then you are using too much of it.  Only use it when you run code that allocates *unmanaged* memory.  Lots of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AddMemoryPressure only tells the GC that more memory is used than what is visible to the GC. It is not connected to any object.

Using AddMemoryPressure will probably cause the clean-ups to run more often but I don't know if that is good or bad for performance. I assume it increases the risk that a clean-up is ran in the middle of something instead of only running on idle.

This line from the documentation is probably what you need
"In more complicated scenarios, where the unmanaged memory allocation changes substantially during the lifetime of the managed object, you can call the AddMemoryPressure and RemoveMemoryPressure methods to communicate these incremental changes to the runtime."

As long as you remove the same amount as you add you can call the methods as you like.

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped that was the case, but I just wanted to check. In normal usage we try not to allocate anything during the calc, but on occasions we can allocate very quickly and I don't want AddMemoryPressure to make things slower

Answer (score 0):

The method is used in pair with RemoveMemoryPressure, to warn the garbage collector of unmanaged resources that might consume a lot of memory.

If a managed object (like a class), uses unmanaged methods, it should inform the garbage collector of it.
That way the garbage collector knows how much memory is really in use, and therefore can give priorities to cleaning it up. The garbage collector cleans up periodically, but when you use AddMemoryPressure, it might clean up earlier, to avoid OutOfMemory errors.
It's important to add the same amount of memory pressure as that you remove!

Comment: Cleaning all small objects can free a lot more memory than cleaning just one big object. But the GC will probably clean them all regardless, as long as they're not reachable.

Comment: We call Remove in tandem, so we do remove the same amount as we add. The question is, does the GC really attach the memory used in AddMemoryPressure to the object being allocated, or is it just used to get a feel of overall thread pressure?

Comment: @Ben: Add/RemoveMemoryPressure are only used to let the GC know you're using memory that it cannot clean up just so it can keep tabs and how much is being used.. I bet they do little more than increasing and decreasing an internal counter.

Comment: They determine how the gc reacts. It can schedule accordingly. And even though its not bound to an object it will take the extra memory in account. Usually this isn't needed, but if you have extremely memory consuming dlls or anything its an option to use it.